# HAXM Install Issue In Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

This has been asked before but I cannot seem to find a solution that works.

I updated Android Studio to version 3.0.1

My Mac is running Sierra version 10.13.3

When I go to run an application in Android Studio I get the following pop up message:
[image]

Many of the solutions suggest to "Uninstall the current HAXM version" that I have in the SDK Manager by unchecking it and then installing it again. When I go there, however, there's nothing to uncheck because the new version was never installed:

[image]

When I try downloading the 6.2.1 version, it does not install. I get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know how can I get this download properly? Thank you!